# Initialization block to be run after constructors

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Let's say I have the below class:

```
template <class Base>
struct Wrapper : public Base {
    using Base::Base;
    
    // ... add functionality ...
};
```

And I want some code to be executed during construction after constructors. I can't add a default constructor, because it won't be run when an inherited constructor is used. One idea is this:

```
template <class Base>
struct Wrapper : public Base {
    bool _ = [this] {
        // initialize ... 
        return true;
    }();

    using Base::Base;
};
```

This does work perfectly well as long as you place it as the last member, but it wastes memory.

Another way is:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct InitBlock {
    InitBlock() {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->init();
    }
};

template <class Base>
struct Wrapper : public Base, private InitBlock<Wrapper<Base>> {
private:
    template <class T>
    friend struct InitBlock;

    void init() {
        // initialize ...
    }

public:
    using Base::Base;
};
```

Which is good, but a bit verbose. And there is nothing protecting `init` from being called again elsewhere. Also, if Wrapper adds members, this is called *before* those are initialized, so it's  not ideal.

What is a better (safe and low on boilerplate) way of doing this?

Comment: the usual way to do something at the end of construction is to place it at the end of the constructor.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number in this case you can't do that, because you don't control what constructors inherited from `using Base::Base;` do.

Comment: ok now I get what the question is about. Though, I dont understand how `using Base::Base` and adding members goes together. You want to have additional members uninitialized on purpose?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number additional members can be initialized with non-static member initialization syntax, like `struct Foo { int foo = 42; };` which automatically injects initialization into all constructors that don't initialize `foo` explicitly.

Comment: Since C++20 you can use an empty class type for the member and mark it `[[no_unique_address]]` which allows the compiler to not reserve any memory for it in the object, although I am not sure whether this is always implemented by the ABIs.

Comment: Maybe, I'm thinking too simple but how about protected constructors and a `make` function (or function template) instead to construct instances and performing the post-init afterwards? (I must admit I love KISS.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/G61czovxe)? It is similar to what someone else proposed previously. It's a good idea but rather disruptive syntactically. If you add an answer, I'll be sure to upvote it ;)

Answer (score 1):

[As mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71333871/initialization-block-to-be-run-after-constructors#comment126089195_71333871), we can use `[[no_unique_address]]` to avoid allocating memory for an empty class. It is honored by all major compilers, except for MSVC. MSVC has its own extension of `[[msvc::no_unique_address]]`. We wrap a macro around this, and it works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define NO_UNIQUE_ADDRESS [[msvc::no_unique_address]]
#else 
#define NO_UNIQUE_ADDRESS [[no_unique_address]]
#endif

template <class Base>
struct Wrapper : public Base {
private:
    NO_UNIQUE_ADDRESS struct Init {} _ = [] {
        puts("Wrapper init");
        return Init{};
    }();
public:
    using Base::Base;
};


struct Foo {
    int i;

    Foo(int i) : i(i) {
        printf("Foo(%d)\n", i);
    }
};

int main() {
    Wrapper<Foo> wfoo(42);
    Foo foo(43);
    static_assert(sizeof(wfoo) == sizeof(foo));
}
```

You still have to take care to place it after all other members to make sure they're initialized by the time we touch them, so it's not ideal.

[See online](https://godbolt.org/z/4bnqob17W)